# Set a calenders Start/EndTime on the NewForm using Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, calendar

I'm trying to set the `start-` and `end time` when creating a new event in a calendar to `00.00` for both fields but i had little to no success as i know very little about client side coding.

I've been digging the web and only found how it was done in [SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55270/unable-to-set-end-time-of-calendar-through-javascript). The only things i came up with is that i should use the [_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabhkv/archive/2009/06/22/javascript-pageload-add-function.aspx) so far.

This is what i got. I have no idea how to get an element nor setting it using Javascript more than `getElementByID` and that i'm not sure if that would work.

```
<script language="javascript">   
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("setEventDates");   
    function setEventDates()   
    {   
        var startTime = .val("00:00");
        var endTime = .val("00:00");
    }   
</script>
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to set the TIME to 00:00, not the date?

Comment: @Submits, Correct, changed the variables to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download jQuery and place it into your Site Assets library, as shown in my example below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../SiteAssets/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("setEventDates");
    function setEventDates() {
        $("#ctl00_ctl34_g_4a492851_365e_4c55_a962_ba0f68262ae1_ff31_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateHours").val("00:");
        setTimeout(function() { $("#ctl00_ctl34_g_4a492851_365e_4c55_a962_ba0f68262ae1_ff41_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDateHours").val("00:") }, 300);
    }   
</script>
```

What comes after the `#` is the ID of the two dropdowns. I'm not sure if the ID will be the same for you so you should check by opening the new calendar event form in your browser, press F12 in  your browser to bring up the developer tools, choose the tool that allows you to click elements on the page, click the dropdown and you'll see in the developer tools pane the `<select>...` tag, which will have an `id` attribute.

The timeout is needed because when the first dropdown is changed to `00` SharePoint will try to change the second date's time to `01`. So you wait for SharePoint to change it to `01` (300ms) then change it back to `00`. Probably not the best approach, but it works.

As a side note, if you don't want a time portion for your date-time field you can specify this in the settings for that field.

Comment: Thanks! Almost there as 300 milliseconds did not stop SharePoint from setting the end time to 01. Tried to set it to 100 milliseconds, and 1 seconds but it did not make any difference.. And i'm using the OOTB calendars content type so i did not want to tinker with the site column as it is used everywhere in the Sitecollection. :)

Comment: So the first dropdown gets set to `00` correctly? If so, it should be able to set the second as well. Try setting the timeout to a much higher value like 3000ms, just as a test. If it works, you'll need to tinker with the timeout value to get it right.

Comment: Tried with 5 seconds and downwards and tried from 100ms without any luck.. did it work for you?

Comment: Yep works perfectly for me. Double-check the IDs of the two elements. Currently, does the first dropdown get changed to `00` and the second is `01`?

Comment: Correct, it shows '00' and '01' no matter the miliseconds/seconds that i try to delay the execute. And i checked my IDs, they are identical for both fields while your differs at _ff31_ and _ff41_ ..

Comment: Ah that's probably you're problem then. They shouldn't be the same. Are you absolutely certain you have the correct IDs? What are the two (identical) IDs out of interest?

Comment: You were right, i was missing out that there were 1 number that were different in the IDs. My sincerest apologies for taking so much of your time. And thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem, and you're welcome.